# REST filter for loopback

Tags: rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

sending the following REST filter to a loopback endpoint

```
filter[where][and][0][polity]=true&filter[where][and][1][or][0][code]=test&filter[where][and][1][or][1][name]=test
```

produces this where JSON object:

```
 {"and":[{"polity":true},{"or":[{"[code]":"test"},{"[name]":"test"}]}]}
```

Please note the unnecessary square brackets around `code` and `name`.

It should be a simple logical test

```
 polity=true & (code=test || name=test)
```

sending the (corrected) JSON to the endpoint works fine.

loopback version: **3.0.0** and **2.22.0**

1. is it a known bug?
2. which loopback module is responsible for convert the request parameters to where object?

Comment: I'm not sure combining operators like this is supported. You could open a ticket [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues) for confirmation. Good question

Comment: @Overdrivr thanks. Interestingly if I use the (correct) JSON format in the query then it works. `?filter={"where":{"and":[{"polity":true},{"or":[{"code":"test"},{"name":"test"}]}]} }`. I have already opened a loopback issue.